# «Вырастили меня как родную дочь» — нужна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Ставить или не ставить запятую перед "как"?

> Эти люди вырастили меня **как** родную дочь.

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147974/discussion-on-question-by--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 1):

Восстановленный ответ

Все зависит **от контекста.**

(1) *Эти люди **вЫрастили** меня, **как родную дОчь.***
Важно, что вырастили. **Контекст:** Эти люди вырастили меня, как родную дочь, да и сейчас помогают во всем.

(2) *Эти люди вырастили меня **как родную дОчь.***
Важно, что "как родную". **Контекст**: Эти люди вырастили меня как родную дочь, не отличая от других своих детей, и они мне как отец и мать.

**Пояснение**

Здесь сравнительный оборот как **трехчастная** конструкция: сравниваются два лица (***меня, как дочь***) через отношение к действию (***вырастили***).

Вспомним, что такой сравнительный оборот не является конкретным членом предложения, но может **приравниваться** к нему, проявляя в большей мере **сравнительное или обстоятельственное** значение.

Между этими значениями **нет** непримиримого противоречия. В предложении одной структуры оборот обособляется, так как автор считает его **попутным сравнением**. А в предложении другой структуры он входит **в состав этого предложения**, автор считает его **смысловым центром** и не обособляет. В этом заключено разное толкование.

**ПРАВИЛО**

**[Розенталь, пункт 4(1)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147#pp147)**

...некоторые предложения допускают двоякое ТОЛКОВАНИЕ и, следовательно, двоякую ПУНКТУАЦИЮ; ср.: Он умер, как настоящий герой (подобно герою’). — Он умер как настоящий герой (‘умер героем’).

**ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ** (об интонационном решении задачи)

Если по правилам возможны **оба решения,** то по интонации можно быстро выбрать подходящее.Нужно прочитать заданное предложение **с контекстом**. Если вы делаете **два ударения**, дополнительно выделяя голосом вырастили, то запятая нужна. Если только **одно ударения** в конце фразы (как родную дочь), то запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 1):

**НЕМНОГО ЮМОРА** (комментарии из удаленного ответа)

***Не сошлись во мнениях***

```
 Каждый человек имеет право на собственное мнение —  при 
 условии, что оно совпадет с нашим.
```

— Да уж,  ударения важнее, чем **грамматика и смысл**.  **Ответ неверный.** Действуйте по правилам Розенталя, а не по ударениям! Или пойдите в РАН, чтобы они реформировали правила. Пусть напишут, что надо писать **по ударениям.**

— Уважаемые участники! **Здесь нельзя писать критику.** Пожалуйста, пройдите на поле ответа.

— Задолбали вы меня этим, здесь **можно писать критику**!  Уважаемые пользователи, этот участник считает **интонационный** принцип самым важным (важнее **смыслового и грамматического**), что не соответствует действительности, и действует по нему. Этот участник **умеет решать только ударениями.**

—  По смыслу? **В качестве родной дочери** — это как? По паспорту, что ли? Нет здесь вашего "as", а есть только "like" (в обособленном или необособленном виде). **Do you understand me?** Нет? Тогда разговор окончен.  Последний наш разговор, вот че слово. **Легче стол убедить в чем-то.** Уважаемые участники! Здесь нельзя писать критику.

— Жесть. **У вас всё в порядке с головой?** Да раз 20 вам говорил, что критика разрешена,  а у вас заела пластинка.  Стол — это вы, вас невозможно переубедить...

**ОБЪЯСНИТЕЛЬНАЯ ЗАПИСКА**

И совсем я не решаю задачи **только ударением**! И у меня **интонационно-структурный** анализ, а не просто интонационный.

**Семантика и грамматика**? Это в первую очередь.
Я рассматриваю трехчастную структуру сравнительного оборота, взятую из **грамматики**, разве нет? И семантику определяю правильно: в обоих случаях это **сравнение**, а отнюдь не тождество.

По структуре предложения определяется возможность **двух решений**, а расстановка ударений уточняет **семантику** (**подчеркивает** важные для понимания смысла слова).

Просьба учесть всё сказанное))